# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x}{x-4y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm interested in solving the following ODE for $y(x)$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x}{x-4y}\:.$$

I tried using the substitution $z = \frac{y}{x}$, which led me to
$$\ln|x| = \frac{1}{4} \ln\left|\frac{2z-1}{2z+1}\right| - \frac{1}{2} \ln|4z^2-1| + c$$ 
but I am now stuck as solving for $x$ gives a nasty looking equation. Any ideas on things to try?

Comment: assuming you did get the right answer for $z$, you can take $\exp$ from both sides and then plug $z = y/x$ and that is the best you can do. Not every simple-looking ODE has nice solution. Implicit solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: Don't plug in $z=y/x$ before solving for $x$, do it after solving for $x$ as a function of $z$.

Comment: Also, trying to write the equation in exact form leads to $M_y=-1$ and $N_x=1$. Just in case, check that you didn't accidentally miss a sign somewhere. You never know, it might turn out to be exact! An integrating factor is also not available.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is written correctly and is not meant to be exact

Comment: This is a standard homogeneous differential equation, so $y =zx$ always works, which lead to a variable separable form. You have done right so far, and just proceed to get an implicit expression, which is totally OK.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x}{x-4y}\:.$$
$$ \frac{dy}{y-x}=\frac{dx}{x-4y}$$
$$ \frac{d(2y+x)}{-2y-x}=\frac{d(2y-x)}{6y-3x}$$
After integration
$$\frac 13\ln|2y-x|+\ln|2y+x|=K$$
Implicit form is good too
$$(2y+x)^3(2y-x)=C$$